# Order-Preserving (Symetric) Encryption or Hash Implementation

Tags: java, encryption, hash, cryptography

There are quite a few papers on order-preserving/homomorphic cryptography, but I haven't been able to find any actual implementations so far.

Do you maybe know an algorithm that has already been implemented and is also being actively used for either symetric encryption or hashing? (Implementation language and license details are not that big an issue, though Java would be prefered.)

Comment: I have a hard time thinking of a practical, order preserving encryption that doesn't utterly suck. At least if you mean things like preserving lexical order on strings, or numeric order on integers.

Comment: Most homomorphic encryption systems(Such as unpadded RSA) only preserve *much* weaker properties.

Comment: Yes, I meant numerical order for integers. What are "much weaker properties"?

Comment: Maybe ask at [crypto](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/)...